# Docker container connection refused with typebot and minio

Tags: docker, containers, minio, portainer

Im trying to connect two containers but its saying connection refused. Im using Portainer to manage containers and im trying to install Typebot and MiniO.

Everything is working fun, the postgress, typebot, others containers can connect with others, all in the same network (i checked this). I've tried create a separate network for Typebot and MiniO with bridge driver but not succesfull.

Im working only locally (localhost) without any server and reverse proxy.

You can see the MiniO S3 Endpoint its configured to 127.0.0.1:9002 and when I try to access in the web or in Postman its works but when the Typebot try to connect in 127.0.0.1:9002 to upload files in the MiniO bucket the connection is refused:

```
REQUEST URL: http://localhost:3000/api/trpc/generateUploadUrl?batch=1
RESPONSE:
[
    {
        "error": {
            "json": {
                "message": "connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:9002",
                "code": -32603,
                "data": {
                    "code": "INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR",
                    "httpStatus": 500,
                    "path": "generateUploadUrl"
                }
            }
        }
    }
]
```

Typebot console log:

```
Something went wrong Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:9002
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1555:16) {
  code: 'INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR',
  name: 'TRPCError',
  [cause]: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:9002
      at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1555:16) {
    errno: -111,
    code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
    syscall: 'connect',
    address: '127.0.0.1',
    port: 9002
  }
}
```

MiniO logs:

```
MinIO Object Storage Server
Copyright: 2015-2023 MinIO, Inc.
License: GNU AGPLv3 <https://www.gnu.org/licenses/agpl-3.0.html>
Version: RELEASE.2023-10-07T15-07-38Z (go1.21.1 linux/amd64)
Status:         1 Online, 0 Offline. 
S3-API: http://10.0.0.6:9002  http://10.0.1.4:9002  http://172.18.0.3:9002  http://127.0.0.1:9002 
Console: http://10.0.0.6:9001 http://10.0.1.4:9001 http://172.18.0.3:9001 http://127.0.0.1:9001 
Documentation: https://min.io/docs/minio/linux/index.html
Warning: The standard parity is set to 0. This can lead to data loss.
```

Just to confirm, here is the response code when I access 127.0.0.1:9002 through Postman (its works fine, the problem is with typebot and minio containers i think):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error>
    <Code>AccessDenied</Code>
    <Message>Access Denied.</Message>
    <Resource>/</Resource>
    <RequestId>requestid</RequestId>
    <HostId>hostid</HostId>
</Error>
```

And when i change the S3_ENDPOINT config in the Typebot compose to "minio:9002" works the first request in the web from typebot but not save the file uploaded in the bucket and the second request from typebot in the web to minio:9002 give error: "(failed)net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED".

First request from Typebot:

```
REQUEST URL: http://localhost:3000/api/trpc/generateUploadUrl?batch=1
REQUEST HEADERS:
POST /api/trpc/generateUploadUrl?batch=1 HTTP/1.1

RESPONSE:
[
    {
        "result": {
            "data": {
                "json": {
                    "presignedUrl": "http://minio:9002/typebot",
                    "formData": {
                        "key": "key",
                        "bucket": "typebot",
                        "Content-Type": "audio/mpeg",
                    },
                    "fileUrl": "http://minio:9002/typebot/fileyrl"
                }
            }
        }
    }
]
```

You see the first request between the containers typebot and minio with URL minio:9002 works fine, but when typebot try to access again:

```
REQUEST URL: http://minio:9002/typebot

PAYLOAD:
file: (binary)

RESPONSE: (failed)net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED
```

I think the errors happen because know the typebot access direct minio:9002 in the web and not  container by container.

Minio Compose:

```
version: "3.7"

services:
  minio:
    image: quay.io/minio/minio
    command: server /data --address ":9002" --console-address ":9001"
    ports:
      - "9001:9001"
      - "9002:9002"
    networks:
      - minha_rede
    volumes:
      - minio_data:/data
    environment:
      - MINIO_ROOT_USER=admin
      - MINIO_ROOT_PASSWORD=adminadminadmin
    deploy:
      mode: replicated
      replicas: 1
      placement:
        constraints:
          - node.role == manager
volumes:
  minio_data:
    external: true
    name: minio_data

networks:
  minha_rede:
    external: true
    name: minha_rede
```

Typebot Compose:

```
version: "3.7"

services:
  typebot_builder:
    image: baptistearno/typebot-builder:2.18.0
    networks:
      - minha_rede
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    environment:
      - DATABASE_URL=postgresql://postgres:AdminAdmin@postgres:5432/typebot
      - ENCRYPTION_SECRET=7/l2NKGhkMUHRV0dt/g8hD2YNopCrAeH
      - DEFAULT_WORKSPACE_PLAN=UNLIMITED
      - NEXTAUTH_URL=http://localhost:3000
      - NEXT_PUBLIC_VIEWER_URL=http://localhost:3001
      - NEXTAUTH_URL_INTERNAL=http://localhost:3000
      - DISABLE_SIGNUP=false
      - ADMIN_EMAIL=myemail@gmail.com
      - NEXT_PUBLIC_SMTP_FROM='Typebot' <myemail@gmail.com>
      - SMTP_AUTH_DISABLED=false
      - SMTP_USERNAME=myemail@gmail.com
      - SMTP_PASSWORD=mysmtppasword
      - SMTP_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
      - SMTP_PORT=587
      - SMTP_SECURE=true
      # Configurações do Typebot e Google Cloud
      #- GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID=
      #- GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET=
      # Configurações do Typebot e Minio
      - S3_ACCESS_KEY=admin
      - S3_SECRET_KEY=adminadminadmin
      - S3_BUCKET=typebot
      - S3_ENDPOINT=127.0.0.1
      - S3_PORT=9002
      - S3_SSL=false
    deploy:
      mode: replicated
      replicas: 1
      placement:
        constraints:
          - node.role == manager
      resources:
        limits:
          cpus: "1"
          memory: 1024M
networks:
  minha_rede:
    external: true
    name: minha_rede
```

I actually search many many many times to solve this but not success. I've tried check if both (typebot and minio) containers are connect in the same network, create separated networks only for typebot and minio, use stack/service name (minio:9002) in the S3_EndPoint and it worked to a certain extent.

Comment: each docker container has a unique, dedicated 127.0.0.1 and can't reach the host's 127.0.0.1, so using localhost or 127.0.0.1 to refer to other containers or the host in docker config is always wrong.

Comment: and what is the recommended to use in localhost?